# Young adult novel from 80s or 90s about werewolves in central Europe

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, werewolf

I'm looking for a novel I read around 1995. I read it in Danish, but I think the author might have been German, though I can't be certain. It was likely written for teens or young adults, and I don't think it was a very old book. I would expect it was written in the 80s or early 90s.

I can't remember anything about the plot, except that it was about a werewolf in central Europe. I believe it was Germany but it could be Austria, Switzerland, or even Poland perhaps. The setting was rural - dark forests, castles, small towns - possibly 18th or 19th century, or at least well away from the modern trappings of big cities.

I believe it opened with a quote of some kind, and possibly had drawings of occult signs, magical symbols, or supposed pages from old grimoires. It may have gone into some detail about the nature of werewolves, including possibly the idea that you could become one by drinking water from a pawprint.

Comment: You don't give us much to go on, now do you? Please [edit] your question if any other details come to mind — what the cover looked like, for instance.

Comment: @SQB I know. I've racked my brain for anything that might help, which sadly isn't much, but if I do think of something more, I'll be sure to add it. Hopefully someone will have an epiphany

Comment: It was _one_ story, right? Not a collection of short stories?

Comment: @SQB Yes, I'm certain it was a single story.

Comment: The only reference I know to drinking water from a werewolf's paw print is in the short story [Only the End of the World Again](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?177601) by Neil Gaiman. The date fits (1994) but nothing else does. It's a Lovecraftian story set in Innsmouth.

Comment: @JohnRennie It's not the one, but it's a potentially interesting connection, at least. Maybe Gaiman got the idea of the paw print from somewhere else.

Comment: I found this, but it is probably not the answer: https://www.wattpad.com/story/1786549-the-life-drinking-from-a-wolf%27s-paw-print-book-3

Comment: @jo1storm Thanks. It's not the one, but I am curious about the origin of this myth about the water from a paw print.